# How to append "px" to array value?

Tags: php

I am developing a wordpress plugin and I am having some difficulties with some basic php.

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; background:{$background_color}; height:{$bar_height}; {$show_hide_border}">
```

As you can see here I have `height:{$bar_height}`.

Here is the call to the array:

```
$bar_height = $options['wprcb_api_number_field_barHeight'] ? $options['wprcb_api_number_field_barHeight'] : 'fit-content';
```

I want it to work this way:
If `wprcb_api_number_field_barHeight` exists, then use this value AND append `px`.
Otherwise the value should be `fit-content`.

I tried to write it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
$bar_height = $options['wprcb_api_number_field_barHeight'] ? ($options['wprcb_api_number_field_barHeight'] + 'px') : 'fit-content';
```

Please suggest how to write it the right way.

Comment: php concatentaion is done with `.`, not `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it this way:

```
  $bar_height = $options['wprcb_api_number_field_barHeight'] ? $options['wprcb_api_number_field_barHeight'] . 'px' : 'fit-content';
```

it should work fine